# Java Unit Test: Test from public method or package private method

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class `Price` with a public method `calculate()` which calls another private method `calculateByA()`.

```
public class Price {
    public SomeObject calculate() {
        if(someCondition) {
            calculateByA()
            // ....
        } else {
            //Calculate something else
        }
    }

    private int calculateByA() {
        //calculation logic
    }
}
```

I want to make a unit test for testing the logic of `calculationByA()`.

I have thought of:

1. Test by calling public method `calculate()` and set `someCondition` to `true`.
2. Change `calculateByA()` to package-private and call it in the test directly.

However, I am not sure which approach is better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test a private function or a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-private-function-or-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or)

Comment: I guess you should have a look at PowerMock for mocking a private method.
Here you can find an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799439/testing-private-method-using-mockito

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954550/unit-test-public-method-that-calls-private-method-and-other-objects-in-java/73401637#73401637)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly dislike the usage of powermock et al. The problem is not that they let you bypass the visibilitysystem (which other language not bother to have at all, see python for example), but that you try to test an implementation detail.

Write your test for visible methods and observe side effects of their private methods. In your example, e.g. test that in someCondition, your results match the expectations in that case.
If you have problems because there are a lot of private methods, consider using a package and split your code up -  it's probably too large anyway. Also use DI luke!

Comment: In general I totally agree. In some cases - if you are working agains an external legacy code (extensions for a third party app), it's necessary to use frameworks like PowerMock from my-point-of-view.

I read the question from the point on how to invoke a private method independently of the best practice aspect.

Comment: @TiemoVorschütz Yes, there are use cases for it, legacy code is a good point. I just like to point out when somebody does something fishy. Especially new guys who might code for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options to your question. Ultimately it is up to you which is best for your situation. However, here are some thoughts on how you can choose between them:

1. Test the method via the public interface

In your case as you mention you can call `calculate` with the correct configuration to execute `calculateByA`. This I believe is the best approach. The code has been structured to mean that the `calculate` is the public interface by which `calculateByA` is accessed. This means that your test will alert people to issues when this behaviour changes. Which in turn means the user of the class will experience a change in behaviour.

2. Change the definition of to protected

As you mention, this will then allow you to call `calculateByA` from other classes in the same package including unit test classes. This is certainly an approach that will allow for easy and independent unit testing of `calculateByA`. However, I don't like this, simply because there is a reason you only want access via the `calculate` function and by changing the access it is tempting for other classes in the same package to call `calculateByA` directly.

3. Use reflection to invoke private method directly

There are a number of technologies that allow you to invoke a private method directly in tests. I won't repeat the excellent answer from by @Tiemo Vorschütz which goes into the details of how to do this. However, this would be my last resort. Simply tests with reflection are more brittle and increase the cost of maintenance of the test suite.

Answer (score -1):

PowerMock lets you test your private method directly:

Price.java:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Price {

  private final boolean someCondition;


  public Price(final boolean someCondition) {

    this.someCondition = someCondition;
  }


  public int calculate() {
    if (someCondition) {
      return calculateByA();
    } else {
      // Calculate something else
      return 0;
    }
  }


  private int calculateByA() {
    final int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 10 + 1);
    return 4711 * randomNum;
  }
}
```

PriceTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Price.class)
public class PriceTest {

  /*
   * Refelection test for a single private method
   */
  @Test
  public void calculateByA() throws Exception {

    final Price instance = new Price(true);
    final int result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(instance, "calculateByA");
    System.out.println(result);
  }


  /*
   * Test public method calculate which invokes private method calculateByA
   */
  @Test
  public void testCalculate() throws Exception {

    final Price instance = new Price(true);
    System.out.println(instance.calculate());
  }
}
```

Dependencies next to JUnit4:

```
</properties>
     <powermock.version>2.0.2</powermock.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.28.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>${powermock.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```