# how to test public method which is calling private method internally

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, junit

```
 /*
this method will create the required manifest file in compatible format such that
quicksight can import data from specified s3 bucket
 */
private JSONObject CreateManifestFileJSONObject(JSONObject ManifestFile){
    JSONArray URIPrefixArray= new JSONArray();
    URIPrefixArray.put(PrefixLocation);
    JSONObject URIPrefixJSONObject= new JSONObject();
    URIPrefixJSONObject.put("URIPrefixes",URIPrefixArray);
    JSONArray FileLocationsArray= new JSONArray();
    FileLocationsArray.put(URIPrefixJSONObject);
    JSONObject globalUploadSettings= new JSONObject();
    globalUploadSettings.put("format","JSON");
    ManifestFile.put("globalUploadSettings",globalUploadSettings);
    ManifestFile.put("fileLocations",FileLocationsArray);
    return(ManifestFile);
}

/*
this method will upload the ManifestFile to same S3 Bucket in which data files is stored
 */
private void UploadManifestFileJSONObjectToS3(JSONObject ManifestFile){
    try {
        AmazonS3 S3Client = new Utility().SetUpS3Client();
        byte[] fileContentBytes = (ManifestFile.toString()).getBytes();
        InputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContentBytes);
        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(fileContentBytes.length);
        S3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(Bucket_Name, ManifestFileName, fileInputStream, objectMetadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void handler() {
    System.out.println("inside the manifest file");
    try {
        JSONObject ManifestFile = new JSONObject();
        ManifestFile = CreateManifestFileJSONObject(ManifestFile);
        UploadManifestFileJSONObjectToS3(ManifestFile);
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to test handler method but handlor method is calling private methods so I do not know how to write the test class for this code.
i want to write unit test for this class please help

this is the test class I am able to create up to this point but it will not surely mock s3 behaviour

```
    @Test
public void handler() {
    ManifestFileHandler manifestFileHandler=new ManifestFileHandler();
    manifestFileHandler.handler();

}
```

Comment: Hi please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954550/unit-test-public-method-that-calls-private-method-and-other-objects-in-java/73401637#73401637)

Answer (score 0):

There are two schools of thought on unit testing private functions. The first is that you make them public (or protected or package accessible) and test them as you would a public function. The second is that if they are private they are part of the encapsulated implementation detail and you only need to test them through the public functions.

My personal view is that complicated private functions are often a sign that you are breaking the single responsibility principle and it's likely you should have logic in private functions that should be split into a separate class that can then be tested through its public methods.

With respect to the code you've posted you have a larger problem than how to test the private functions: your class depends on other classes that you don't have control over. You have no way of mocking the behaviour of those classes to test various scenarios or to verify that they have been called correctly. I suspect it is this problem that is really behind your question.

As an example, I would suggest you inject a `S3Client` into your class rather than create it internally through `new Utility().SetUpS3Client()`. That way you can mock its behaviour and verify it is called correctly by your code. Attempting to do that with the real version of this class will be challenging.

So using this model, your code might look something like:

```
public class ManifestFileHandler {
    private final S3Client client;

    public ManifestFileHandler(S3Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    private void upload(JSONObject manifestFile) {
        ...
        client.putObject(...);
    }

    public void handleManifest() {
        ...
        upload(manifestFile);
        ...
    }
         
}
```

And your test code (using mockito):

```
@Test
void testManifestUpload() {
    S3Client client = mock(S3Client.class);
    ManifestFileHandler handler = new ManifestFileHandler(client);
    handler.handleManifest();
    verify(client).putObject(expectedObject);
}
```

If you need to capture the argument passed to `putObject` and assert various aspects of it then that is possible with most mocking tools (including mockito) but is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: But the question is not about how to test private methods.  It's about how to test the public one.  And of course, the answer is to pretend there AREN'T private methods in the picture - just test that the public method does the right thing.

Comment: ohhh so if i am understanding right you wanted to say just call that method and if file is uploaded to s3 then its correct otherwise not?

Comment: but the problem is then the manifest file will go into the real s3 bucket but in testing I do not want this so what should I do

Comment: Actually, looking at your code, the thing you really want to mock is the `Utility` object.  Have a look at [this article](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation), which has a couple of suggestions.  I am the original author, but I think it's changed a bit since I wrote it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Not sure about mocking Utility. If the code only deals with S3 buckets it'd make more sense to me to inject the s3 bucket interface into the object rather than a utility for creating them.

Comment: @A.BHAVE to answer your question - you definitely do not want your tests to have to check anything in AWS. That's why you need to mock the interface.

Comment: @sprinter Yes exactly that i want but i don't know how to mock s3 behavior.i am writing the test class which i have written up to this point but this surely will not mock s3 I am updating the ques with my test class please have a look

Comment: @A.BHAVE I've added an example of injecting the client and then mocking it in the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can test private methods with the help of PowerMock provides utilities which uses reflection to do certain things.
check the below example,
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-private-method-example-with-powermock/