# How to unit test a public method that calls a private method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Here is a very basic example to illustrate my point

```
class SomeClass {

    publicMethod1(param1, param2) {

        if (param1 === "some value") {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // do stuff
        }

        this.privateMethod(true);

    }

    publicMethod2(param1, param2, param3, param4) {

        if (param3) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // do stuff
        }

        this.privateMethod(false);

    }

    privateMethod(param) {

        // do stuff

        let obj = database.getObject(param); // call to database

        if (obj.property === "random") {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

I've done a bit of research into this topic but didn't find any people asking the exact question I'm asking. I think I'm clear that I should only be unit testing my public methods and not private ones. But I'm just wondering **how** I should be testing my public methods that make calls to private methods that are within the same class.

Should I simply be testing to make sure that private method was called? Or should I be delving into the logic of the private method to make sure I test every possible route of execution? And if it's a "yes" to the latter, I was wondering if it is common to reuse unit tests when dealing with private methods that are called multiple times (like in the example above).

Comment: First, you don't have any private methods in that class. But, if you did (precede the method name with #), your unit tests would need to stress every public method with calls to the private method. Code coverage will ensure you've covered all branches/lines/etc.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sorry, I may be a little confused by your answer. Are you saying I should go with the first option I laid out or the second one? Should I simply be testing to make sure that private method was called? Or should I be delving into the logic of the private method to make sure I test every possible route of execution?

Comment: You should do both. Make sure the private method was called and ensure all the logic of the private method was exercised by your tests. You have two choices to accomplish this: 1. run your tests through a debugger and step through the private method (this is impractical) 2. use a code coverage tool that shows you what parts of your private method were executed.

Comment: Just to very clear in my meaning, check out this repl for an explanation: https://repl.it/@randycasburn/Jester#README.md

Comment: please refer to my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954550/unit-test-public-method-that-calls-private-method-and-other-objects-in-java/73401637#73401637)

Answer (score 1):

Call your public method and observe behavior and state of your system. Are other components called? Does any state change? This is the things you are testing for. If that happens because the method calls other methods or it is doing it all by itself does not matter.

Another way of thinking about it: Imagine your private method does not exist, but the code is part of your public methods. Now you test these public methods and everything is fine. Then you notice that the last part of the two public methods is the same, except for whatever-that-boolean-does and you are extracting that code into a private method. Does that make your tests invalid?