# How do I write a unit test on a method that calls another private method in that class?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class that generates some tokens. I have some external dependencies and unit tested those dependencies by mocking and verified the number of times the method was called. However, After calling those external dependencies, I have a private method called to get the token. Ex:

```
var res = GetToken(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Do I have to unit test on that statement and if so how?

Comment: Just test the public interface. What the public method does under the hood is none of your concern: you don't care whether it calls other private methods, calls into other classes, whatever. You just care that the outputs it gives you are correct for the inputs you give it

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954550/unit-test-public-method-that-calls-private-method-and-other-objects-in-java/73401637#73401637)

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't need to unit test private methods. You unit test the public methods that *use* those private methods, mocking any external dependencies. You verify that the outputs of public methods are correct, which assumes that the results of the private methods that they call are also correct. That gives you the freedom to *change* the private implementation without braking your unit tests (so long as the public interface is unaffected).

There *may* be cases where you want explicitly unit test a private method in isolation, but it is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Hi, I'm fairly new to unit tests. So, I still have some questions. Yes, I am testing a public method that calls the private method. That private method uses some external dependencies and calls another private method. How do I unit test that statement calling the private method in my question. How do I assert the returned token from the method call?

Comment: Is the token part of the public output? If not, how would the wrong result from the private method affect the output? Could you mock something that gives a wrong result in the private method and verify that it affects the public output as expected? That's about as specific as I can be without any detail.

Answer (score 1):

Every private method is called by a public method in the end. Maybe not directly, but somewhere in the callstack there is a public method. You test this public method, and because it calls the private method, you indirectly test it. An example:

```
public class Test
{
   public int Result {get;private set;}

   public PerformAction(int a, int b)
   {
       int value = a + b;
       SetResult(value);
   }
   
   private void SetResult(int value)
   {
      Result = value;
   }
}
```

If you test `PerformAction`, you call it with e.g. 4 and 5, and then you check whether the `Result` property has the value 9. By that, you tested also the private `SetResult` method indirectly. If it had a bug, your test would fail.

Don't try to test private method directly. In theory, it would be possible via reflection, but it leads to very brittle tests which have to change quite often. In general, you should test observable behaviour (which is commonly public), no implementation details (which are commonly private).

Comment: Hi, I'm fairly new to unit tests. So, I still have some questions. Yes, I am testing a public method that calls the private method. That private method uses some external dependencies and calls another private method. How do I unit test that statement calling the private method in my question. How do I assert the returned token from the method call

Comment: If you want to have a more detailed answer, you should show more of your code.